# Really annoying error [python/p3d]

Tags: python, panda3d

I have this part in my code right here which somehow orginates from Panda 1.7.2/Python 2.4:

```
Factions = tuple(lambda [outmost-iterable]: for x in [outmost-iterable]: AvatarType(faction = x)(range(9)))
(Undead, Navy, Creature, Townfolk, Pirate, TradingCo, Ghost, VoodooZombie, BountyHunter) = Factions
```

When i run the code IN Python 2.7/Panda 1.8.1, it gives me this error:

```
Factions = tuple(lambda x for x in [outmost-iterable]:
                                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I have tried every method possible to fix, but i still can't figure it out, it's not in the docs and i'm really desperate. Is there a way to fix it a bit, so it's compatible with 2.7?

Comment: please format your code properly either by highlighting and clicking the code button or indenting it 4 spaces.

Comment: Wow, Python 2.4's lambda syntax must have been pretty different to the current version. I think you want something like `Factions = tuple(AvatarType(faction=x) for x in range(9))`, but it's hard to tell because the syntax has changed so much.

Comment: Your syntax doesn't look right at all. What are you trying to do?

Comment: @IanAuld: Just checked the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2.4/ref/lambdas.html) and apparently that's what the syntax looked like in 2.4, very hard to parse as someone who started with 2.7/3

Comment: @Marius Well I'm certainly glad they changed that. If that's the case a list/generator comprehension is probably what you want over a lambda, OP.